# Azure - Azure Redis Cache connect to on-prem datacenter

Tags: azure, redis, architecture, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I am building an architect where we would like to add a caching layer for on-prem datacenter and some of the web apis that are already on Azure.

I know that the Web APIs that are in Azure can connect to the Azure Redis Cache easily. I wanted to check if on-prem datacenter can connect to the Azure Redis Cache? If yes, how?

Is there any documentation that talks about the process? I am looking to keep the Azure Redis Cache Private so the Web APIs can access the cache through private link

Comment: [Azure Cache for Redis with Azure Private Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-private-link)